# x86-64 MSVC++/Intel C++ change size of int, long, etc

Tags: c++, visual-c++, icc

I wish to have the following sizes when I compile (using Visual C++ 2015 and/or Intel C++ 16.0)

- char 32 bits unsigned (for UTF-32 characters)
- short 32 bits
- int 64 bits
- long 128 bits
- Pointers and size_t 64 bits (which they are currently)

Is this possible to change? My current solution uses the macros:

```
#define int int64_t
#define char char32_t // Is this unsigned?
#define short int32_t
#define long __int128
```

But it has problems, like "int main" doesn't work... And I can't defined "signed int" "unsigned int" etc. as macro names can't have spaces

EDIT: The reason I want to do this is to improve legibility (so I don't have to write int64_t...) and also to make any code I use, that uses int/char/short/long to automatically upgrade (when recompiling) to using 64/32/32/128 bits, without having to modify it directly.

Comment: The only way to make `signed int` behave as you expect is to modify the compiler. Which, being Microsoft, you won't be able to.

Comment: What you're trying to do looks like a _spectacularly bad_ idea to begin with. It smells like [an X Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Could you edit your question explaining _why_ you want to do that?

Comment: The standard explicitly says *"A translation unit shall not #define or #undef names lexically identical to keywords"*. `int main` is but one problem - consider what happens to any standard header you include.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this. The only proper way to achieve this is by introducing your own types and using them instead.

Also, when using types like `int` you must not depend on the underlying size apart from what the standard says (i.e. in case of `int` the only guarantee is that it's at least 16 bits). What you want to achieve is a dependency you shouldn't have, and that would make you code completely unportable. Besides, I don't see why `int64_t` would be less legible than using `int`. Also, the redefining you want would come unexpected to other developers and thus is likely to cause bugs. Using your own types makes it explicit that the types are different.

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary to use macro when you define unsigned int, you can write code like the following:

`typedef unsigned int UINT;`

now you can also write code like this:

`#define UINT balabala`